# Heat Transfer, with energy generation

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I have a study question that I am not able to solve:

> A cylindrical electrical resistance is used to heat water.
>
> - Radius is 2 mm and the length is 80 cm.
> - Electrical conductivity of the resistance is 3x10<sup>3</sup> mOhm<sup>-1</sup> while the thermal conductivity is 4 W/mK.
> - Water temperature is 30 °C and the convection coefficient is 100 W/m<sup>2</sup>K.
> - Maximum allowable surface temperature of the resistance is 150 °C.
>
> a.    Derive the radial temperature distribution inside the resistance
>
> b.    Calculate the maximum electrical current in A
>
> c.    Calculate the resistance and heat generation rate
>
> d.    Calculate the central temperature

#### What I could establish so far

Now, I got stuck, because I can not find the heat generation due to electricity, though everthing else comes of by finding the T(x). I do not want an explicit answer though, just a way of how I can solve it.

Comment: I tried to model it , then use the general  formula for radial temperature distribution but couldn't get anything

Comment: Please read [this Q&A](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/368) for some guidance about what we expect of homework-type questions.

Comment: @Jodes has a good walk-through of calculating the power dissipation.  You're probably meant to assume that it's a uniformly distributed volumetric heat generation (Power/Volume of the resistor).  Then you're just solving $\nabla^2=\dot{q}$.

Comment: @Dan, do you have a link that explains that formula? Does it cover both the radial heat flow and the uniform generation of heat?

Answer (score 1):

Using [This tutorial](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/convective-heat-transfer-d_430.html), I calculate the following:

Assume surface temperature of 150°C. Use water temperature of 30°C, and convection coefficient of 100W/m^2K.

> Surface area =  2 x PI x 2x10^-3 x 0.8 = 1.0053 cm^2

Therefore:

> Power = 100 x 0.010053 x (150 - 30) = 120.636W

The resistance:

> Resistance = (3 x 10^3 x 0.8) / 0.010053 = 239 kΩ

The current flowing through it:

> I = sqrt (P / R) = sqrt ( 121 / 239k ) = 22.5mA